# Under what conditions is this map $0$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $X$ be a convex subspace of euclidean space.  Let $b \in X$.  Let $\sigma : \Delta^n \rightarrow X$ and define $(b.\sigma) : \Delta^{n+1} \rightarrow X$ as: $$(b.\sigma)(t_0, t_1, \dots, t_{n+1}) =\{ b \text{ if $t_0 = 1$} \text{ and } t_0 b + (1-t_0) \sigma(\frac{t_1}{1-t_0}, \dots, \frac{t_{n+1}}{1-t_0}) \text{ if $t_0 \neq 1$} \}$$

***When will $b.\sigma$ ever equal $0$?***

If $\sigma = 0$, then I would think it equals $0$, but by the definition above it would be $t_0 b$ for all $(t_0, \dots)$ in the domain of $\Delta^n$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sigma = 0$? @OliverG

Comment: @NoelLundström  By $\sigma = 0$, I mean the identity of the group $S_n(X)$.

Comment: @NoelLundström I'm realizing now that I don't know what the identity of $S_n(X)$ is.  I see that $b.0 = b.(\sigma - \sigma)$, for some $\sigma \in S_n(X)$, and then $b.\sigma - b.\sigma = 0$ as it's a homomorphism, but I now am confused on what the relationship between $0$ and $b.0(t_0, \dots) = t_0 b$ is.

Comment: Do you know what  $S_n(X)$ is?

Comment: Yes, it's the free abelian group with basis $\{\sigma : \Delta^n \rightarrow X\}$.  Elements of $S_n(X)$ are of the form $\gamma = \sum b_{\sigma} \sigma$.

Comment: Ok then you know that elements of $S_m(X)$ are not maps. They are formal sums of maps. It does not make sense to talk about what $(b.0) (t_0 ,..., t_{n+1})$ is as $b.0$ and $0$ are not maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $S_n(X) \cong \oplus_{\sigma \in C(\Delta^n, X)} \mathbb{Z}$ is the free abelian group on the set $C(\Delta^n, X)$, the elements are formal sums of the form $\sum_{\sigma \in C(\Delta^n, X)}a_\sigma \sigma$ where $a_\sigma \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a_\sigma = 0$ for all but finitely many $\sigma$. The $0$ element of this group is the sum where $a_\sigma = 0$ for all $\sigma$.

For a particular simplex $\sigma_0 \in C(\Delta^n, X)$ we consider it an element of $S_n(X)$ as the sum where $a_{\sigma_0} = 1$ and $a_\sigma = 0$ for all other $\sigma$; in particular this element is never $0$. So for any $\sigma$ the element of $S_{n+1}(X)$ representing the cone $b\cdot \sigma$ is also non-zero, because its coefficient $a_{b\cdot \sigma} = 1$ is non-zero.